# How to get random rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, random, rows

My personel table id colum is 1,2,3, 4,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,20

How to get random 5 rows and id not in 1,2,6

My personel table has 100K records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could order the table by `rand()` and `limit` the results:

```
SELECT   id
FROM     personel
WHERE    id NOT IN (1, 2, 6)
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT    5
```

Comment: OK.Thanks for your great answers

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the ones you don't need using `not in` and order by `rand()` function to randomize the order, then `limit` rows to 5.

```
select * from table
where id not in (1,2,6)
order by rand() limit 5;
```

Comment: OK.Thanks for your great answers

Comment: @Ahmet cheers mate :)